# Email Input Pattern Attribute

Tags: php, html

I am in the process of using pattern for my email input field (HTML for email) to be `1234567Z@student.glasgow.ac.uk` see code snippet below, I am not getting glasgow as full (only gla appears).

Have tried to manipulate this part of the email with various other strings but unable to get the correct format as outlined earlier.

Any reason why I am getting this with the code:

```
Email address:
<input name="email" type='email' pattern=".+ (@student.glasgow.ac.uk)" required />
<input style="float: right;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try by this code

```
<input type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" />
```

Comment: hi ahmed thanks for the quick response but i want to restrict the email to have @student.glasgow.ac.uk as a must and anything before @ symbol could be anything ....ive tried this <input name="email" type='email' pattern=".+(@student.glasgow.ac.uk)" required /> the result is 1234567z@student.gla.ac.uk but i want the .gla to be full as glasgow, thanks in advance...

Comment: try this live demo[http://output.jsbin.com/ozeyag/19]

`function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return re.test(email);
}`

Comment: hi the link is broken and how do i implement the  function !

Comment: you will write  this function in script tag javascript and run this function onclick , onblur events etc.