# Validate input field with regex pattern using angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

How to validate the password field with **regex pattern** using angular2 without using the formbuilder.

I am able to validate the maxlength and minlength for input field but the following validation with regular expression is not working.

I tried in the following way, but it is not working

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-icon name="lock" item-left class="placeholder-icon"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label floating primary>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="login.password"
        ngControl="password" type="password" #password="ngForm"
        pattern="/^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*? ]).*$/">
    </ion-input>
</ion-item>         
<p *ngIf="password.errors && password.errors.pattern" danger padding-left>
    Password must contain one lowercase, one uppercase, one number, one
    unique character such as !@#$%^&? and be at least 6 characters long.
</p>
```

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32314567/email-input-pattern-attribute

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom directive to apply / wrap the `Validators.pattern` validator.

Here is an implementation of this approach:

```
const PATTERN_VALIDATOR = 
  new Provider(NG_VALIDATORS, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => PatternValidator), multi: true});

@Directive({
  selector: '[pattern][ngControl],[pattern][ngFormControl],[pattern][ngModel]',
  providers: [PATTERN_VALIDATOR]
})
export class PatternValidator implements Validator {
  private _validator: Function;

  constructor(@Attribute("pattern") pattern: string) {
    this._validator = Validators.pattern(pattern);
  }

  validate(c: Control): {[key: string]: any} { return this._validator(c); }
}
```

You can use this directive this way:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    (...)
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="login.password" ngControl="password" 
          type="password" #password="ngForm"
          pattern="/^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*? ]).*$/">
    </ion-input>
    (...)
  `,
  directives: [ PatternValidator ]
})
```

This article could interest you:

- https://medium.com/@ttemplier/implementing-custom-validator-for-template-driven-forms-292eb355447c#.xjjznv3z3